# Building a MultipartFormData API response

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, multipartform-data

I need to build an API that returns a JSON object and attached files in byte array form. So to do this I thought of using MultipartFormDataContent class in C#. I have the API written something like this.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodName(Params){
    ......statements......
    var responseContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    ......statements......
    responseContent.Add(new StringContent(jsonString), 'JSON Object');
    ......statements......
    responseContent.Add(byteArrayContent);
    return responseContent;
}
```

This is giving an error while building the project about not being able to convert the responseContent to IHttpActionResult. So I tried explicit casting like so.

```
return (IHttpActionResult)responseContent;
```

But this throws a runtime error about not being able to convert to IHttpActionResult. So how would I go about returning responseContent. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `ResponseMessageResult`, it supports `IHttpActionResult`:

```
return new ResponseMessageResult(new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = responseContent })
```